# Show a modal when user enter the voice channel

Tags: discord, bots

I need show the modal when user join in voice channel, but the voice channel not have a interaction param. How to do it?

@aclient.event
async def on_voice_state_update(member, before, after):

This event detects user join a voice channel, i need show modal entire this.

Can anybody helpe me please.

Open modal when user join a voice channel.